# serialization in json.NET doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
jw.WritePropertyName("info"); 
serializer.Serialize(jw, res);
if (res[2] == true)
{
    jw.WritePropertyName("healer"); jw.WriteStartObject();
    jw.WritePropertyName("running"); 
    jw.WriteValue(res[1] == true ? (checkBox1.IsChecked == true ? true : false) : false);
    jw.WritePropertyName("main"); jw.WriteStartObject();
    serializer.Serialize(jw, new bool[] { true, true, true, true, true, true });
    jw.WriteEndObject(); // here
    jw.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Could somebody tell me please why this code doesn't work?
without line `serializer.Serialize(jw, new bool[] {...}});` everything is working fine.

Comment: Please post the error message w/ stack trace

Comment: Why don't you use simply `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)`

Comment: http://screenshooter.net/0741095/nxeeemx

Comment: Please don't post updates to your question like that. Include the text of the exception - and the stacktrace - in an edit to your original question. If the link breaks, this question becomes less valuable for any future finders. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of exception is that you are telling writer that you will write an object and you are writting an array. Try like this:

```
jw.WritePropertyName("healer");
jw.WriteStartObject();
jw.WritePropertyName("running"); 
jw.WriteValue(res[1] == true ? (checkBox1.IsChecked == true ? true : false) : false);
jw.WritePropertyName("main");
serializer.Serialize(jw, new bool[] { true, true, true, true, true, true });
jw.WriteEndObject();
```

Or as an alternative like this:

```
jw.WritePropertyName("healer");
jw.WriteStartObject();
jw.WritePropertyName("running"); 
jw.WriteValue(res[1] == true ? (checkBox1.IsChecked == true ? true : false) : false);
jw.WritePropertyName("main");
var myArray = new bool[] { true, true, true, true, true, true };
jw.WriteStartArray();
foreach (bool myValue in myArray)
{
    jw.WriteValue(myValue);
}
jw.WriteEndArray();
jw.WriteEndObject();
```